# PHP Backslash Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a username with domain in PHP, and am having issues with backslashes either being completely stripped or "doubled up". I've tried a ton of different fixes, and nothing is working.

```
$domain = "domain";
$username = "username";
$adfs = stripslashes($domain.'\\'.$username);
$dynamicsClient = new dynamicsClient($adfs, $password, $URL, 1);
```

What I want as the end result is domain\username.

Seems simple enough, but because of escaping, I can't get this to work. I'm new to PHP, so there must be a fix.

Please help.

Comment: just remove stripslashes()

Comment: what wrong with `$domain.'\\'.$username`?

Comment: I did that, and I end up with domain\\username. It doubles up. :(

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
$domain = "domain";
$username = "username";
$adfs = $domain.'\\'.$username;
```

Comment: I did that, and I end up with domain\\username. It doubles up. :(

Comment: @Mayhem Did you used echo or where do you use it?

Comment: I'm passing it to a function:

Comment: @Mayhem Please update your question with the function so we can see how you use it!

Comment: $dynamicsClient = new dynamicsClient($adfs, $password, $URL, 1);

If I use $adfs = stripslashes($domain.'\\'.$username);, I get no slashes.

If I use $adfs = $domain.'\\'.$username; I get two slashes.

Comment: @Mayhem Where do you use `$adfs` in the constructor and where do you see that it has 2 backslashes ?

Answer (score 1):

You are stripping the slash that you've properly escaped.
Change:

```
 $adfs = stripslashes($domain.'\\'.$username);
```

To:

```
 $adfs = $domain.'\\'.$username;
```